# How to loop through different Dataframes to check in pandas whether any value in a given column is different than 0 and save the result in an array

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, loops

The goal of this python pandas code would be to loop through several dataframes - results of an sql query -, check for every column of each dataframe whether there is any value different than 0, and based on that, assign the column name to a given array (ready_data or pending_data) for each dataframe.

The code is as follows:

```
#4). We will execute all the queries and change NAN for 0 so as to be able to track whether data is available or not
SQL_Queries = ('dutch_query', 'Fix_Int_Period_query', 'Zinsen_Port_query')
Dataframes = ('dutch', 'Fix_Int_Period', 'Zinsen_Port')
Clean_Dataframes = ('clean_dutch', 'clean_Fix_Int_Period', 'clean_Zinsen_Port')

dutch = pd.read_sql(dutch_query.format(ultimo=report_date), engine)
clean_dutch = dutch.fillna(0)
Fix_Int_Period = pd.read_sql(Fix_Int_Period_query.format(ultimo=report_date), engine)
clean_Fix_Int_Period = Fix_Int_Period.fillna(0)
Zinsen_Port = pd.read_sql(Zinsen_Port_query.format(ultimo=report_date), engine)
clean_Zinsen_Port = Zinsen_Port.fillna(0)

#5). We will check whether all data is available by looping through the columns and checking whether values are different than 0

dutch_ready_data=[]
dutch_pending_data=[]

Fix_Int_Period_ready_data=[]
Fix_Int_Period_pending_data=[]

Zinsen_Port_ready_data=[]
Zinsen_Port_pending_data=[]

for df in Dataframes:
    for cdf in Clean_Dataframes:
        for column in cdf:
            if (((str(cdf)+[column]) != 0).any()) == False:
                (str((str(df))+str('_pending_data'))).append([column])
            else:
                (str((str(df))+str('_ready_data'))).append([column])
```

The error message I keep getting is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-fa18d45f0070> in <module>
     13     for cdf in Clean_Dataframes:
     14         for column in cdf:
---> 15             if (((str(cdf)+[column]) != 0).any()) == False:
     16                 (str((str(df))+str('_pending_data'))).append([column])
     17             else:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me out.

Thousand thanks!

Comment: In order to get a full answer, you need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Regarding your specific error, it is self-explanatory: you are trying to concatenate a string (`str(cdf)`) with a list (`[column]`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer David! Apologies for not having provided an MRE. Regarding the problem of concatenating a string with a list, is there any way to merge both so as to reflect the changing loop parameters? Thousand thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to, do but if you remove the brackets around `column` you would be concatenating two strings.